# How can I get all posts in Facebook with a certain hashtag

Tags: facebook, hashtag

I'm building a contest app which requires to find images posted by anyone in their Facebook public timeline with a specific hashtag. User doesn't need to like our page or anything. we just want to gather all the posts that is using that particular hashtag.

Could anyone tell me how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Graph API v2.0 and the now gone public post search, you don't have the possibility to search for hashtags anymore.

There's the Public Feed API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/public_feed), but this is restricted to FB partners only.

I don't see that you can achieve what you desire. Sorry.

Comment: This is achievable via the api version 1.0. the problem was the access_token which instead of api_key|api_secrate we have to generate a $appsecret_proof. which can be done by following:

    $appsecret_proof= hash_hmac('sha256', $access_token, $app_secret);

Comment: The docs say otherwise: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v1.0#search Searches for `Posts` require an User Access Token. Be aware that v1.0 will only work until April 30th 2015!